# Swipable card Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I am looking for this widget. When you swipe left or right, the card changes its order. (The one of front goes to the back)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a way to stack widgets and show only one at a time you can use the IndexedStack widget.
https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/IndexedStack-class.html